# How do I implement a decorator in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator

I am trying to implement [this](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/02/download-functionality-rails-ecommerce.html) in my app.

The article says that I must create a decorator - but it doesn't go into much detail about exactly how to do that. This is the code:

```
module CartDecorator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module InstanceMethods
    def is_downloadable?
      items = self.items.collect { |li| li[:variant].item }
      items.all? { |i| i.is_downloadable }
    end

    def has_downloadable?
      items = self.items.collect { |li| li[:variant].item }
      items.any? { |i| i.is_downloadable }
    end
  end
end

Piggybak::Cart.send(:include, CartDecorator)
```

I am not sure if I should add that code to some `model.rb` (for what it's worth, I don't have a `piggybak_cart.rb` in my `app/models/` folder).

I tried running `rails g decorator Cart` and that didn't work.

What I have done is put the above code in `app/helpers/cart_helper.rb`.

Then when I tried to run a `rails g command` (for something else), I am now getting this error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant CartHelper (NameError)
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:136:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the above code into `app/decorators/cart_decorator.rb`

the decorators folder will be new and be autoloaded when you start your rails app. when this is run `Piggybak::Cart.send(:include, CartDecorator)` it will decorate your Piggybag::Cart with the methods you declared above.

Comment: Thanks much. Just what the doctor ordered :)